# Can't answer own question

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to answer my own question: http://answers.ros.org/question/41798/gazebo-simulation-crashes-on-collision-with-wall/, but cannot see the post answer button for this question or other questions I have asked.

Was this facility removed with the last answers.ros update? If so, can we bring it back please.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41889/can%27t-answer-own-question/) by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2871 on 2012-08-20

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-08-21**:
I suggest you file a bug ticket against answers.ros.org at https://code.ros.org/trac/ros to track this issue. Please post an answer with the link to that bug ticket once you create it.

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-08-21**:
@Eric Perko: Yes. This certainly looks like a bug. https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/4033. Won't be able to post it as an answer though...

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-08-22**:
O right... good point. I'll post it for you.

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-08-31**:
Don't know what you guys did, but I can't answer my own questions [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/42167/error-building-fuerte-on-osx/) and [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/42734/how-does-robot_pose_ekf-work/) either. I don't see the answer button either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This issue seems to have been resolved (I am now able to answer this question)

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@piyushk has filed a bug ticket to track this: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/4033

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-08-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4